# Making an OpenGL app without Windows.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I've set the linker to additional dependencies opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;sfml-main-d.lib;

When I run it, I get loads of errors about APIEntry or something in one of the OpenGL files. SFML is also set up fine.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{

}
```

It works fine if I include Windows.h, but I really don't want to make it windows-specific (Since the only reason I switched to C++ from C# is for cross platform and I'm not too fussed on Java)

[image: Image of my errors]

Comment: For future readers, if you have trouble installing GLFW like I did, here's a link which helped me a lot http://shawndeprey.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/setting-up-glfw-in-visual-studio-2010.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're starting out you're probably not interested in the lower level stuff as setting up your own OpenGL context and such. I would recommend you take a look at GLFW at http://www.glfw.org/ - it is what I prefer for OpenGL. It is open source and cross platform for both Windows, linux and MAC.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not really just starting out- I've been using the XNA framework, and the LWJGL Java OpenGL wrapper, both for a long time. Would there be any significant performance impact if I used GLFW?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the purpose, reading the page it looks like it just simplifies OpenGL integration or wraps it or something, so I'm guessing the impact on performance would be very minor?

Comment: Nope, not at all. It is a very modern OpenGL library. It is being coded on today, with a new version released some days ago. I use it and I know a lot who does as well. I can warmly recommend it.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, I think it'd be much easier use (For obvious reasons) especially since it's my first graphical C++ project. (Also I'm too lazy to figure out all the OS-specific coding).

Comment: Good luck then. I will also recommend reading www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: I'm feeling really stupid now, but how do I install this? Is it the same way as SFML? Extract the lib files into the VS\lib directory, and the same for the include files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an installation guide with it. Long time since I installed on windows - but yeah, just copy the lib and include files to VS.

Comment: @AshleyDavies: Please stop copying files into the VS directories. Just have a place on your harddrive where you put them and change the include and library paths to look there. Putting stuff in your VS directories makes it very easy for you to break you VS installation.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use OpenGL, then you should employ a proper [OpenGL Loading Library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) to get your function pointers. These libraries have headers that will include whatever platform-specific stuff is needed to make the header work, using appropriate #defines and so forth.

Comment: Which one of them would you recommend?

Comment: @AshleyDavies: Well, I [kinda wrote one of them](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html), so it's not a fair question ;)

Comment: @AshleyDavies They're all good really, my experience with GLEW has been good and it's the one I use but whichever one works, works right :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether to accept this answer or Mads'. I'll probably try both and accept whichever one I end up using. I'll upvote both either way. Thanks for answering so fast too